# Need link for downloading firefox 24 on AIX

Tags: firefox, aix

I need to install Firefox 24 on AIX 7.1.
Could you please help me to get the link from where I can download the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,there is no current build of firefox on AIX.  The last time was many years ago.

Comment: As per the information I have, It seems that 3.6.28 is the most recent version that we have for AIX. Is this the case. The version intended i.e. 24 is not available for AIX. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would be of great help if I can get the details about the latest version of Firefox available.

Comment: You found the same one that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IBM only provide a really old Firefox: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/browsers/

Why do you want a browser for AIX?

Comment: I have one link where version 3.6.28 is available. http://www.linkitup.de/ForAIX/Firefox/                              I not able to make out whether this is the latest version for AIX. I need to run one application on AIX OS and need to check the browser compatibility for the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Most AIX systems will run as servers in headless mode, so browser access probably comes from remote systems I would have thought.